# Android How to apply camera effect only for half screen?

Tags: java, android

I made a camera app with Camera2 API in Android, a fullscreen camera without taking pictures and I apply it a negative effect to all the preview, what I want to do is the negative effect only be applied to half of the preview, example:

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOkNy.png)

Here is my code:
[Link to my code on github](https://github.com/germanPineda/camera2photo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/photo/AndroidCameraApi.java)

I will appreciate the help because I am so lost i don't know what to do :(

Comment: I would suggest troubleshooting where exactly you need to change your code because scanning a whole script on GitHub is both time-consuming and exhausting. P.S. Everybody stop using `Camera2` and use `CameraX`.

Comment: Why don't you try dividing the image into two parts and then applying the effect to one of them?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting on StackOverflow I will keep it in mind and i didn't know about CameraX I will check it, thanks for your time and help. I tried dividing the image but it didn't work.

Comment: No need to apologize, we are were beginners at some time. Check out CameraX and post the results

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll have to do custom rendering here, since nothing in the camera2 or cameraX APIs will do this for you.

Basically, you'll need to send the camera output to the GPU, and use GL shader code to write your own custom negative effect.

That's a lot of boilerplate to get to where you want, but it's unlikely you'll have any other realistic option.  While ImageView and some other Android UI APIs allow applying some effects or color transforms to their output, I don't think you could get them to give you half the view as negative, without significant performance problems.

To send camera image data to the GPU, use a SurfaceTexture as the output target, and then use the SurfaceTexture's texture ID in your EGL code as the source texture.